# How to change fragment's text from Service class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains a `TextView`. Also, I have a class that extends `Service`.
How can I change fragment's `TextView` text from this Service class?
I tried to create an instance from my fragment to use it for calling an update method inside the fragment, but I realized that I can't call `getSupportFragmentManager()` inside a `Service` class.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such purpose Android have broadcast receiver.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Ok I got it,  I created an `intent`, then I puted my data into that intent, after that I used `sendBroadcast(intent)`, then I created a `BroadcastReceiver` in my fragment to get the data :) , it worked, thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Noor you wellcome. Now you know about one more main component of android framework. This knowledge will be useful in future;)

Answer (score 0):

you can get getSupportFragmentManager() always and everywhere with below code using context:

```
((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

and to get fragment:

```
Fragment myFragment=((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
```

after you access fragment you have two options to do your desired action.first is easier,second is more secure.

**Option One->TextView Public**
make textview public and setText() that textview from your service class like:

```
myFragment.myTextView.setText("some_text");
```

**Option Two->TextView Private**
make textview private and create a method to setText() textview in fragment like:

```
public void setTextViewText(String text){
  textView.setText(text);
}
```

and call it from your Service Class like:

```
myFragment.setTextViewText("some_text");
```

Comment: Could you please write the whole declaration of the fragment object? thank you

Comment: i updated my answer.tell me if problem still occurs.

Comment: as you are in a service class replace 'context' with 'this' or 'ClassName.this'